# Reconstructing generic types at runtime with Guice via Types and TypeLiterals

Tags: generics, reflection, runtime, guice

I have a few types that are like this

```
// a value that is aware of its key type (K)
Bar<K>
// something that deals with such values and keys
Foo<V extends Bar<K>, K>
```

How would one recreate Foo such that you could consume it in Guice?  The bit I'm stuck on is how to cross reference the K from Bar to the 2nd parameterized type of Foo.

So for example,

```
WildcardType kType = Types.subtypeOf(Object.class);
WildcardType barType = 
   Types.subtypeOf(Types.newParameterizedType(Bar.class, pipeKey));
ParameterizedType fooType = 
   Types.newParameterizedType(Foo.class, pipelineableType, pipeKey);
```

Really this seems wrong as it's basically:

```
Foo<V extends Bar<? extends Object>, ? extends Object>
```

Which is not the same thing as:

```
Foo<V extends Bar<K>, K>
```

As in the latter case I *know* that K is a consistent type.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the JavaDoc for [Binder](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/latest-javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html):

> Guice cannot currently bind or inject
>   a generic type, such as `Set<E>` all
>   type parameters must be fully
>   specified.

You can create bindings for `Foo` when `K` and `V` are bound.
If you need to make bindings for `Foo` for more than one type of key, you can make a method that makes it easier to do these bindings. One way to do that is to create a method like this in your module:

```
<K, V extends Bar<K>> AnnotatedBindingBuilder<Foo<V, K>> bind(Class<K> keyType,
    Class<V> barType) {
  ParameterizedType bType = Types.newParameterizedType(Bar.class, keyType);
  ParameterizedType fType = Types.newParameterizedType(Foo.class, barType,
      keyType);

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  TypeLiteral<Foo<V, K>> typeLiteral =
      (TypeLiteral<Foo<V, K>>) TypeLiteral.get(fType);

  return bind(typeLiteral);
}
```

Then if you have these classes:

```
class StringValue implements Bar<String> {
  ...
}

class StringValueProcessor implements Foo<StringValue, String> {
  ...
}
```

You can create a binding like this:

```
bind(String.class, StringValue.class).to(StringValueProcessor.class);
```

...so that Guice could inject into a class like this:

```
static class Target {
  private final Foo<StringValue, String> foo;

  @Inject
  public Target(Foo<StringValue, String> foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }
}
```

Comment: interesting, I hadn't thought of binding in that way. 

What I'm really looking for the ability to search for a set of bindings that match some specification that may include some type params, e.g. all bindings that are Foo<V<String>,String> though I suppose in that case it's enough to simply look for Foo<?,String>... hmmm

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100784/guice-spi-find-bindings-by-wildcard-types ?

Comment: yes that is my Q as well, I have implemented that in a way that works so far... but have been wondering how to extend it to a more general case. On reflection I'm not sure it's even needed as it's just a wildcard really. I need to think about it some more...

Answer (score 1):

Guice's factory cannot build `TypeVariable` instances. You'll need to implement this interface directly as you need it.

Note that Guice doesn't allow bindings for types that aren't fully-qualified. For example, you can bind a `Map<String, Integer>` but you can't bind a `Map<K, V>`.