# How can I write a generic FactoryModuleBuilder?

Tags: generics, types, dependency-injection, guice

I'd like to know how to represent a generic version of the following binding that won't fail with `xxx cannot be used as a key it is not fully specified`

```
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().
   implement(new TypeLiteral<SomeClass<T,?>>(){}, 
      new TypeLiteral<SomeOtherClass<T, U>>(){}).
   build(SomeFactory.class);
```

It seems that the `implement` method isn't available with a parameterized type parameter.

Comment: Im curious what your SomeFactory looks like.

Comment: @johncarl I'm happy to share, but I don't know how it would help:  `interface SomeFactory<T extends BaseClass<?>> {
   SomeClass<T, ?> create(T t);
}`

Comment: Why is your SomeFactory parameterized?  It seems like this would work:interface SomeFactory { <T extends BaseClass> SomeClass<T, ?> create(T t); }

Comment: Ok, I'll look into it further.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible because of the way Guice uses type literal parameters.  TypeLiterals require concrete types and, as you see from the exception, cannot accept generic parameters.

To quote @jesse-wilson

> Note that Guice doesn't allow bindings for types that aren't
>   fully-qualified. For example, you can bind a `Map<String, Integer>` but
>   you can't bind a `Map<K, V>`.
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/1117878/654187

You can "fully qualify" these bindings as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1120990/654187

But I doubt this is what you want.

The good news is you can still write this factory without assisted injection easily:

```
public class SomeFactory{
    @Inject
    private SomeDependency someDependency;

    public <T> SomeClass<T, ?> buildSomeClass(T t){
        return new SomeOtherClass<T, Object>(t, someDependency);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps.  This does not use Guice to instantiate `SomeOtherClass`.  The whole purpose of AssistedInject is to avoid manually writing factories.

Comment: Updated my answer with further research.

Comment: I really appreciate all the effort you've put into this--it's just that the manual factory you proposed won't inject any of `SomeOtherClass`'s non `@Assisted` parameters--will it?

Comment: Ah, you could inject into the SomeFactory class, which in turn can construct your SomeOtherClass with those instances.  Updated the example.

Comment: That means every time `SomeOtherClass` needs to be changed to add new injected parameters, the factory has to change as well.

Comment: I would claim that is a sustainable solution because the compiler would warn you of problems by not being able to compile the SomeFactory class if the SomeOtherClass' constructor changed.

Comment: True--I quickly edited the post and changed the unintended inflammatory wording but you read it too soon.  Either way, I really don't want to abandon `@Assisted` injection.  And at your suggestion, I tried removing the class's generic parameter and ended up getting binding errors as [explained in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3791999/403455).

Comment: There is another option I hinted at in my answer which would use @Assisted injection, but you would have to iterate over all instances that may be used in the generic type.  If your generic type encompasses just a couple classes this may be a viable solution.  If not, there are frameworks that will scan your classpath and tell you all implementations/extensions of a given type.  Depending upon your environment this my work (probably not in Android)  (btw, didn't think comment was inflamatory ;-))

Answer (score 1):

Alen Vrečko [posted](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-guice/XJDnJX4uemQ/o58p_qElSG4J):

> Imho the best you can do with generics is something like
>
> `install(new Assist2<Payment, RealPayment>(PaymentFactory.class){});` or
>
> `install(new Assist3<SomeClass<Foo, Bar>, SomeOtherClass<Foo, Bar>,
>   SomeFactory<Foo>(){});`
>
> Should be pretty easy to implement this approach. Just look in the
>   source of TypeLiteral.
>
> If you absolutely need type parameters something like:
>
> `install(new CustomAssist<Baz>(){});` where
>
> `CustomAssist<T> extends
>   Assist<SomeClass<Foo,T>,SomeOtherClass<Foo,Bar>{...`
>
> might be possible but not trivial to implement. But a lot of fun.

Answer (score 0):

To follow on from @johncarl

If you are just injecting someDependency then you'll be getting the instance when the factory is created.  To make it work like a FactoryModuleBuilder constructed factory you'll need to inject the Injector

```
public class SomeFactory{
    @Inject
    private Injector injector;

    public <T> SomeClass<T, ?> buildSomeClass(T t) {
        return new SomeOtherClass<T, Object>(t, injector.getInstance(SomeDependency));
    }
}
```