# How do I bind a single implementation to multiple generified interfaces in Guice?

Tags: java, generics, guice

I have a set of 15-20 classes that depend on a class that implements generic interface with bound type parameters. The interface looks like this:

```
interface Handler<F extends Foo, T extends Foo> {
    T handleFoo(String methodName, F myFoo);
}
```

And a single implementation of Handler that uses reflection to deal with all the specialised cases of Foo, because they're all "similar but different".

```
class ConcreteHandler<Foo, Foo> implements Handler<Foo, Foo> {
    T handleFoo(String methodName, F foo) {
        // do your thing
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to use this class in a type-safe way in its collaborators, like:

```
@Inject ACollaborator(Handler<Bar, Baz> barHandler) {...}
```

where `Bar` and `Baz` both extend `Foo`. Unfortunately, Guice complains that `Handler<Bar, Baz>` is not bound when I try this in my module:

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<Handler<? extends Foo, ? extends Foo>>() {}).to(ConcreteHandler.class);
```

I have also tried the following, which causes a compiler error because `ConcreteHandler` is not a subclass of `Handler<Bar, Baz>`:

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<Handler<Bar, Baz>>() {}).to(ConcreteHandler.class);
```

I have so many of these Collaborator objects that I am not keen on the thought of implementing Handler for each combination of types, and putting in 20 separate binding statements for them.

How do I accomplish what I'm attempting with Guice, that is binding a single concrete implementation to a single interface with different generic parameters?

Comment: Did you mean `bind(new TypeLiteral<Handler<? extends Foo, ? extends Foo>>() {}).to(ConcreteHandler.class);` ?

Comment: Yes, thank-you for pointing that out, @PaulBellora.

Answer (score 2):

You can manage to do this by creating the TypeLiteral representing the binding target, probably with a raw type involved.

You'll see an example of how to do this in this question:
   [Reconstructing generic types at runtime with Guice via Types and TypeLiterals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114384/reconstructing-generic-types-at-runtime-with-guice-via-types-and-typeliterals)

Basically what you'll needs is something to construct the Key of each Handler<> you want bound.

Then you can say something like:

```
bindHandler(Bar.class, Baz.class);
```

Which will:

1. create a `TypeLiteral<ConcreteFoo<Bar, Baz>>`
2. create a `TypeLiteral<Foo<Bar, Baz>>`
3. bind the latter to the former

Also I think in your example ConcreteHandler should implement Handler[?]

Comment: You're right about the omission of ConcreteHandler's implements clause. Thanks. I'll give your suggestion a shot and report back.